# How to stored procedure function to calculate grade

Tags: oracle, plsql

i have table's name is TB_M_Evaluation, the structure table is like this:
[i am facing trouble when i want to show the table using stored procedure function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy7T9.png)

**i have already create the function and it works:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_EVALUATION(KNOWLEDGE IN NUMBER, PRESENTATION IN NUMBER, CODING IN NUMBER, ERD IN NUMBER, DURATION IN NUMBER)
   RETURN varchar2 is variable_LetterGrade varchar2(3) := '';
   variable_duration Number(11) := 0;
   variable_Score Number(11) := 0;  
 BEGIN
  IF DURATION <= 10 THEN
   variable_duration := 90;
  ELSIF DURATION > 10 OR DURATION <= 20 THEN
   variable_duration := 80;
  ELSE
   variable_duration := 70;
  END IF;
   variable_Score := (KNOWLEDGE + PRESENTATION + CODING + ERD + variable_duration)/5;
  IF variable_Score >= 84 THEN
   variable_LetterGrade := 'A';
  ELSE
   variable_LetterGrade := 'B';
  END IF;
  RETURN variable_LetterGrade;
END;
```

**but when i create the procedure it is show error like this:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_EVALUATION
   IS CURSOR VARIABLE_LETTERGRADE IS
 SELECT
   KNOWLEDGE,
   PRESENTATION,
   CODING,
   ERD,
   DURATION,
   variable_LetterGrade
 FROM TB_M_EVALUATION
 ORDER BY C1 variable_LetterGrade%rowtype;
BEGIN
  FOR C1 IN variable_LetterGrade LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Your Knowledge value is: ' || C1.KNOWLEDGE);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Your Presentation value is: ' || C1.PRESENTATION);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Your Coding value is: ' || C1.CODING);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Your ERD value is: ' || C1.ERD);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Your Duration value is: ' || C1.DURATION);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Your Letter Grade is: ' || C1.variable_LetterGrade);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

[could someone help me how to resolve this? :( need your help all. thank you in advance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYaBu.png)

Comment: `ORDER BY C1 variable_LetterGrade%rowtype` ? Try geting rid of that part.

Comment: @kfinity done, but now the error is show ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: Did you delete the semicolon too? You need that. :)

Comment: @kfinity yes, i deleted it with the semicolon too :'D

Comment: Which means what? That it works now?

Comment: @Littlefoot still not works. just change the error message from SQL Statement Ignored to ORA-00905: missing keyword :(

Answer (score 0):

Saying (i.e. *commenting*) that it still doesn't work, here's code that *works* (i.e. doesn't return an error).

Sample table first:

```
SQL> create table tb_m_evaluation
  2  (knowledge    varchar2(10),
  3   presentation varchar2(10),
  4   coding       varchar2(10),
  5   erd          varchar2(10),
  6   duration     number,
  7   variable_lettergrade varchar2(10)
  8  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into tb_m_evaluation values
  2    ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 1, 'e');

1 row created.
```

Function:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_EVALUATION
  2    (KNOWLEDGE IN NUMBER, PRESENTATION IN NUMBER,
  3     CODING IN NUMBER, ERD IN NUMBER, DURATION IN NUMBER)
  4     RETURN varchar2 is variable_LetterGrade varchar2(3) := '';
  5     variable_duration Number(11) := 0;
  6     variable_Score Number(11) := 0;
  7   BEGIN
  8    IF DURATION <= 10 THEN
  9     variable_duration := 90;
 10    ELSIF DURATION > 10 OR DURATION <= 20 THEN
 11     variable_duration := 80;
 12    ELSE
 13     variable_duration := 70;
 14    END IF;
 15     variable_Score := (KNOWLEDGE + PRESENTATION + CODING + ERD + variable_duration)/5;
 16    IF variable_Score >= 84 THEN
 17     variable_LetterGrade := 'A';
 18    ELSE
 19     variable_LetterGrade := 'B';
 20    END IF;
 21    RETURN variable_LetterGrade;
 22  END;
 23  /

Function created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_EVALUATION
  2     IS CURSOR VARIABLE_LETTERGRADE IS
  3   SELECT
  4     KNOWLEDGE,
  5     PRESENTATION,
  6     CODING,
  7     ERD,
  8     DURATION,
  9     variable_LetterGrade
 10   FROM TB_M_EVALUATION
 11   ORDER BY variable_LetterGrade;
 12  BEGIN
 13    FOR C1 IN variable_LetterGrade LOOP
 14    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Your Knowledge value is: ' || C1.KNOWLEDGE);
 15    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Your Presentation value is: ' || C1.PRESENTATION);
 16    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Your Coding value is: ' || C1.CODING);
 17    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Your ERD value is: ' || C1.ERD);
 18    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Your Duration value is: ' || C1.DURATION);
 19    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Your Letter Grade is: ' || C1.variable_LetterGrade);
 20    END LOOP;
 21  END;
 22  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> exec sp_evaluation;
Your Knowledge value is: a
Your Presentation value is: b
Your Coding value is: c
Your ERD value is: d
Your Duration value is: 1
Your Letter Grade is: e

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```